# mysql foreign key using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not able to create Foreign key in phpmyadmin .
I used the following queries to create 2 tables.The first table was created but when i use 2nd query i got the error as

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order ( Orderid INT NOT NULL, cost INT, CustId INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Or' at line 1
```

This is my first table:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  CustId INT NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (CustId)
);
```

and this is my 2nd table:

```
CREATE TABLE order
(
 Orderid INT NOT NULL,
 cost INT,
 CustId INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(Orderid),
 INDEX (CustId),
 FOREIGN KEY (CustId) REFERENCES customer (CustId)
);
```

So what i am doing wrong here? how do i create this tables and also implement the foreign key in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I think `order` is reserved key word in mysql so try some other names like `orders` or put quotation around your table name as `'order'`

Comment: The title of this question should be changed. The fact that the table definition includes a foreign key constraint is not at all relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a MySQL reserved word (it's used in `ORDER BY` clauses), you have to enclose it in backticks if you want to use it as the name of a table or column.

```
CREATE TABLE `order`
(
 Orderid INT NOT NULL,
 cost INT,
 CustId INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(Orderid),
 INDEX (CustId),
 FOREIGN KEY (CustId) REFERENCES customer (CustId)
);
```

You'll have to remember to put it in backticks whenever you reference it in a query. You'll save yourself lots of trouble if you simply choose a different name for the table.

Comment: I wonder why you thought the problem had something to do with the foreign key, when the error message very clearly says that it's a syntax error near `order`.

Comment: @Barmar: It's probably for the benefit of the next person that encounters this same problem. They will be able to easily find this question by searching for "mysql foreign key using phpmyadmin". :)

Answer (score 0):

Also this would help you:

If you ask to me, backticks should always be used. But there are some reasons why a team may prefer not to use them.

Advantages:

- Using them, there are no reserved words or forbidden chars.
- In some cases, you get more descriptive error messages.
- If you avoid bad practices you don't care, but... in real word,
  sometimes they are a decent way to avoid SQL injections.

Disadvantages:

- They are not standard and usually not portable. However, as long as
  you don't use a backtick as part of an identifier (which is the worst
  practice I am able to imagine), you can port your query by
  automatically removing backticks.
- If some of your query come from Access, they may quote table names
  with " (and maybe you can't remove all the " blindly). However,
  mixtures of backticks and double quotes are allowed.
- Some stupid software or function filters your queries, and has
  problems with backticks. However, they are part of ASCII so this
  means that your software/function is very bad.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html